# Using dplyr to enumerate redundant values in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` with two sets of IDs, where both may be redundant.

Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c("id.1","id.1","id.1","id.1","id.1","id.2","id.2","id.3"),
                 id2 = c("id.1.a","id.1.b","id.1.a","id.1.c","id.1.b","id.2.a","id.2.b","id.3.a"))
```

What I want to do is add another ID column in which `df$id1` will have a numeric suffix, increasing in value, that follows the order of `df$id2`.

So for the example above the resulting data.frame will be:

```
res.df <- data.frame(id1 = c("id.1","id.1","id.1","id.1","id.1","id.2","id.2","id.3"),
                     id2 = c("id.1.a","id.1.b","id.1.a","id.1.c","id.1.b","id.2.a","id.2.b","id.3.a"),
                     id3 = c("id.1.01","id.1.03","id.1.02","id.1.05","id.1.04","id.2.01","id.2.02","id.3"))
```

So since `id.1` maps to `id.1.a` twice, to `id.1.b` twice, and to `id.1.c` once, it becomes: `id.1.01, id.1.03, id.1.02, id.1.05, id.1.04`

Any idea how to pull this off with `dplyr` or `tidyr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. We group the rows by `id1`, since that is the grouping we want to count rows on.
2. We arrange them by `id1` followed by `id2`
3. We create a new column with that appends the `row_number` to the end of `id1`. Since the rows are arranged by `id1` and `id2`, the `row_number` will keep that order

Example:

```
df %>%
    group_by(id1) %>%
    arrange(id1, id2) %>%
    mutate(id3 = paste0(id1, '.', row_number()))


# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id1 [3]
  id1   id2    id3   
  <fct> <fct>  <chr> 
1 id.1  id.1.a id.1.1
2 id.1  id.1.a id.1.2
3 id.1  id.1.b id.1.3
4 id.1  id.1.b id.1.4
5 id.1  id.1.c id.1.5
6 id.2  id.2.a id.2.1
7 id.2  id.2.b id.2.2
8 id.3  id.3.a id.3.1
```

Answer (score 3):

We could directly use `row_number` on 'id2'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id1) %>% 
   mutate(id3 = paste0(id1, ".", row_number(id2)))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id1 [3]
#  id1   id2    id3   
#  <fct> <fct>  <chr> 
#1 id.1  id.1.a id.1.1
#2 id.1  id.1.b id.1.3
#3 id.1  id.1.a id.1.2
#4 id.1  id.1.c id.1.5
#5 id.1  id.1.b id.1.4
#6 id.2  id.2.a id.2.1
#7 id.2  id.2.b id.2.2
#8 id.3  id.3.a id.3.1
```